# How to transfer album art images to Cowon iAudio 9 mp3 player with linux music software

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mp3-player, music-management, banshee

I have got a Cowon iAudio 9 music player and want to display the album art images of the albums on it. The player does support this feature but only when there is a *.jpg file inside of the album folder or the image is embedded into the music file itself (did not tried that).

At the moment I'm using banshee as music management software and I like it. The album art is downloaded automatically for each album and when the player is connected it is beeing recognized and I can drag & drop albums or single songs.

The only problem is that the album art is not transfered along with the albums. The player does support MTP and MSC usb connections and is mounted as removeable usb drive to the system (Ubuntu 10.10). I would be glad if there's a solution to do that with banshee but other software solutions are welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

All I needed to do was creating a file on the players root dir and call it `.is_audio_player` and put the following lines into it:

```
audio_folders=Music/
output_formats=audio/ogg,audio/x-ms-wma,audio/mpeg,audio/wav,audio/x-flac,audio/mp3
cover_art_file_type=jpeg
cover_art_file_name=cover.jpg
```

The files are transfered as usual and the cover.jpg gets created automatically!